# sublime text 2: ant: I keep getting permission denied when running the build.xml

Tags: ant, sublimetext2

I've read through all the documentation on this for Sublime Text 2 and finally figured out how to overwrite the build system, but I'm still getting the following error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied
[cmd:  [u'ant', u'-s']]
[dir:  /Users/mydirectory/Sites/thesite]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

What directory is it referring to when it says Permission denied?  I have set the dir to 755, but that doesn't seem to help.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you logged in as admin? To change configuration files for Sublime Text, you need to have `7`. Try to edit the file in command line and use `sudo` this time.

Comment: @ArslanAli that is completely incorrect. If you run Sublime as any user, it generates the config files in that user's `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2` directory (under OS X, which the OP is using). No `sudo` is required.

Comment: Do you own `/Users/mydirectory/Sites/thesite`? If not, your user needs to have write permission to the directory, and all its files and subdirectories.

Comment: Yes, this is on my personal computer, which I own full admin rights.  I set that directory with permissions of 755.

Comment: I know that everything works because I've run it from the command line, but I'm still getting that dreaded issue with Permission Denied and I really don't know what the directory is with the problem.  I've tried chmod'ing the build.xml directory and the sublime-build file, but nothing seems to work.  Any ideas?